# Recursive Where Clauses SQL CTE Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-query

I'm having trouble making the use of a iterative SQL script.

What I need is to calculate inventory of documents of every month, but I'm not able to iterate over the where clauses, what I need is to make every `EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0)` (from columns and WHERE) something like `EOMONTH(@VarDate, n+1)` and it has to be in T-SQL.

The result I'm trying to get is the next one from VarDate 2019 to Today every month.

| Expediente | VarDate |
| --- | --- |
| 15004/2018 | 2019-01-31 |
| 500/2019 | 2019-01-31 |
| 669/2019 | 2019-01-31 |
| ...... | ....... |
| 16232/2018 | 2022-06-30 |
| 13945/2018 | 2022-06-30 |

This was my first attempt

```
DECLARE @VarDate date
SET @VarDate = '2019-01-01';

DECLARE @EndDate date
SET @EndDate = EOMONTH(@VarDate,3);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
        CAST(numexp AS nvarchar) + '/' + CAST(añoexp AS nvarchar) Expediente, 
        EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0) VarDate
    FROM 
        syn_TControl_Movimientos_expediente m
    WHERE
        m.fase = 1 
        AND (m.Fecha <= EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0) AND (m.CveMov IN (1,3))
        AND (m.ConsMov = (SELECT MAX(ConsMov) AS Expr1 
                          FROM syn_TControl_Movimientos_Expediente AS m2
                          WHERE (NumExp = m.NumExp) 
                            AND (AñoExp = m.AñoExp) 
                            AND (Fecha <= EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0))))) 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        c.Expediente, EOMONTH(c.VarDate, 1) 
    FROM
        cte AS c
    WHERE 
        EOMONTH(c.VarDate, 1) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

But the result is always the same as it was not affecting the `WHERE` section.

| Expediente | VarDate |
| --- | --- |
| 15004/2018 | 2019-01-31 |
| 500/2019 | 2019-01-31 |
| ...... | ....... |
| 15004/2018 | 2019-02-28 |
| 500/2019 | 2019-02-28 |
| ...... | ....... |
| 15004/2018 | 2019-03-31 |
| 500/2019 | 2019-03-31 |
| ...... | ....... |
| 15004/2018 | 2019-04-30 |
| 500/2019 | 2019-04-30 |
| ...... | ....... |

My second approach has the next error SQL Error [467] [S0001]: GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'cte'.

```
DECLARE @VarDate date
SET @VarDate = '2019-01-01';

DECLARE @EndDate date
SET @EndDate = EOMONTH(@VarDate,3);

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECt
        CAST(numexp AS nvarchar) + '/' + CAST(añoexp AS nvarchar) Expediente, 
        EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0) VarDate
    FROM 
        syn_TControl_Movimientos_expediente m
    WHERE 
        m.fase = 1 
        AND (m.Fecha <= EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0) AND (m.CveMov IN (1,3))
        AND (m.ConsMov = (SELECT MAX(ConsMov) AS Expr1 
                          FROM syn_TControl_Movimientos_Expediente AS m2
                          WHERE (NumExp = m.NumExp) 
                            AND (AñoExp = m.AñoExp) 
                            AND (Fecha <= EOMONTH(@VarDate, 0))))) 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CAST(numexp AS nvarchar) + '/' + CAST(añoexp AS nvarchar) Expediente, 
        EOMONTH(c.VarDate, 1) VarDate
    FROM 
        syn_TControl_Movimientos_expediente m, cte c
    WHERE
        m.fase = 1 
        AND (m.Fecha <= EOMONTH(c.VarDate, 1) AND (m.CveMov IN (1,3))
        AND (m.ConsMov = (SELECT MAX(ConsMov) AS Expr1 
                          FROM syn_TControl_Movimientos_Expediente AS m2
                          WHERE (NumExp = m.NumExp) 
                            AND (AñoExp = m.AñoExp) 
                            AND (Fecha <= EOMONTH(c.VarDate, 1)))))
        AND EOMONTH(c.VarDate, 1) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT * FROM cte
```

Any ideas on how to make any of this two to work?

Comment: Please, provide some sample data of the table

Comment: @PauloFernando added as suggested

Comment: I was expecting data from the [syn_TControl_Movimientos_expediente], i must be able to run the query, only inspecting won't be enough

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED .... Used WHILE instead of CTE

```
DECLARE @Inicio date
SET @Inicio = '2019-01-01'
DECLARE @Exp TABLE (Expediente varchar(255), Periodo date)
WHILE EOMONTH(@Inicio,0) <= EOMONTH(GETDATE(),0)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @Exp
   select cast(numexp as nvarchar)+'/'+cast(añoexp as nvarchar) Expediente, EOMONTH(@Inicio,0) Periodo
    FROM syn_TControl_Movimientos_expediente m
    where m.fase=1 and (m.Fecha <= EOMONTH(@Inicio,0)  AND (m.CveMov IN (1,3))
    AND (m.ConsMov =(Select MAX(ConsMov) as Expr1 from syn_TControl_Movimientos_Expediente as m2
    WHERE (NumExp=m.NumExp) and (AñoExp = m.AñoExp) and (Fecha <= EOMONTH(@Inicio,0)))))
   SET @Inicio = DATEADD(Month,1,@Inicio)
END;
SELECT * FROM @Exp
```